# What do I do about these errors when attempting to install Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, thinkpad, iso

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my new laptop ("new" as in received today), a Lenovo P43s. I downloaded the .iso file from the Ubuntu website (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and verified it using these instructions (modified for 20.04 LTS rather than 18.04 LTS): https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

However, on trying to boot up the new machine from a USB containing the .iso file (created with balenaEtcher), I get a couple of errors during the boot and during the file checks before reaching the installation options. See the attached photos.

I assume this means that I shouldn't go ahead and install the OS on my machine, but I'm curious as to what I should do in order to correct these errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkgFr.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zECK3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error1 is not critical, it just tells that the kernel can't read certain parts of your hardware (namely tpm - a clock and some acpi registers). That is not critical.

Error 2 indicates that your iso image or you filesystem might have a flaw.
So you should try to rewrite the iso file unto you usb stick. Make sure to [checksum](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) the iso file with the given MD BEFORE you put it on a stick/SD_Card.

Comment: Suggested clarification of Error 2: That error usually means a corrupt or incomplete download. Re-download the .iso, then [verify the download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu), then re-make the install USB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did already verify the checksum, but on downloading the .iso again and flashing to disk, I was able to complete the installation with no errors.